# Fast user switching affects color profile

Tags: macos, display, color

I have a 2013 MacBook Air running Mavericks. I have a "work" and a "personal" account that I switch between throughout the day using Fast User Switching. Sometimes when I switch accounts, the (built-in, only) display turns an awful, washed-out blue. I thought the behavior was random, but I've figured out how to reproduce it consistently.

1. Have multiple accounts.
2. Log into one account from the Login Window.
3. Use Fast User Switching to switch to a different account *that you're not already logged into.*

Every time, the screen will turn blue. And when I look at the display preferences, I'll see that the factory color profile, "Color LCD", is not listed, and instead OS X is using the generic "Display" profile.

[image: Imagine that this screenshot is a hideous shade of blue]

The screen will stay blue until I log out of the account that triggered the bug. Logging into the same account from the Login Window poses no problem.

For what it's worth, here's what the Display Preferences dialog normally looks like:

[image]

I have no idea why "Display" is listed four times. Perhaps it's a clue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this very detailed post.  I have the same issue, and only a workaround, not a solution.

Workaround consists in going into monitor prefs, change screen resolution to a lower res, then get back to "optimal screen res", and then you original color profile is available for selection.

A bit tedious, but once done, I can fast-switch back and forth and the color setting will remain intact (until I leave either session).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

thanks, this was very helpful. I couldn't find the Color LCD option either, but I clicked on the "calibrate" button on the right and clicked through the several steps of set up. It adjusted everything correctly. When I switched back to my other profile, the blue color was back, and I no longer had the Color LCD option, but I went through the same process (in Display Profile, I clicked through the Calibrate process). Now both user displays are correct -- no blue tint. Hope this helps someone else.